# Mark newly added rows on query refresh

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is there a way to mark a newly added row on a query refresh?

Example:
We currently have following rows :

Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
Data 4

On the next refresh, the rows look like this:
Data 1
Data 2
Data 2.1
Data 3
Data 4

Is there a way to mark the newly added row (Data 2.1)?

Comment: Not unless you plan to preserve the previous version somewhere, no

Answer (score 2):

@horseyride's comment is right... but you're talking Excel, so if you load it to a worksheet then you *do* have a previous copy!

1. Make a backup copy of your workbook.
2. Make a new query that pulls the output table *directly* from the worksheet, and then choose only the key columns and whatever other columns you want to carry forward instead of overwrite.
3. Duplicate your original query to a new one.
4. Change your original query to something that merges the old version from the worksheet (#2) to that duplicate of the original query (#3), plus however you want to indicate when a row from #3 isn't in #2!

This is also a great technique when you want to use powerquery pull in some columns while allowing other columns to be editable.